# how to disable simultaneous connections by one user on oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

i am using oracle 12, and hoping to find how can i enable or disable simultaneous connections for my database for each user.
i found codes regarding dispatchers and other ones including the following codes:

```
SHARED_SERVER_SESSIONS 
MAX_DISPATCHERS
CONNECTIONS
SESSIONS
POOL
```

in addition to other codes that didn't find suitable for my case .Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new profile as

```
CREATE PROFILE <profile_name> LIMIT 
   SESSIONS_PER_USER          1
   CPU_PER_SESSION            UNLIMITED 
   CPU_PER_CALL               <some_value>
   CONNECT_TIME               <some_value>
   LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION  DEFAULT 
   LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL     <some_value>
   PRIVATE_SGA                <some_value>
   COMPOSITE_LIMIT            <some_value>;
```

note: choose other parameters as per requirement, you can get current profile parameter values from dba_profile view and use them in the above query. Before that get the profile name of the user using below query

`SELECT profile FROM dba_users WHERE username = <user_name>;`

Then ALTER USER

`ALTER USER <user_name> PROFILE <profile_name>;`

Comment: I got, table or view does not exist when trying to select from dba_users

Comment: and what does connect time means ? can i set the timeout period after which if a user stayed idle , he will be logged out automatically ?

Comment: Table does not exist error is faced because you have not been granted SELECT_CATALOGE_ROLE, use this [document link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) for information about various parameters.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, YOUR RESPONSE WAS VERY FAST AND HELPFUL, REALLY APPRECIATE IT :d