# How to set connection timeout period in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, timeout, sqlplus

i am working on a project where i have to set the period after which if a user stayed idle, he will be logged of automatically and prompt again for username and password.
if found some articles about :

```
connection pool
```

and

```
pds.setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(18000)
```

and

```
pds.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(60);
PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
```

but didn't find them related to my problem, can anyone help ?

Comment: Start by turning off the caps lock :-)

Comment: i did not understand what u meant

Comment: Do not enter the title in all caps (see Nicholas's edit).

Comment: The [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026962) discussed profiles, and included a link to the documentation that includes the `CONNECT_TIME` resource parameter; doesn't that do what you want?